# How do I make the USB monitor Lenovo Think Vision lt1421 work?

Tags: usb, xorg

How to make usb monitor **Lenovo Think Vision lt1421** work on ubuntu. On official site I see drivers only for [windows](http://support.lenovo.com/en_US/downloads/detail.page?&DocID=DS020544). When I plug it in: it is not detected. On windows it worked fine.

Comment: Hasn't 13.10 support for USB monitors?

Comment: Try to load udlfb kernel module with 'sudo modprobe udlfb' . That is the kernel driver for monitor that use displaylink technology. Make sure you have xserver-xorg-video-displaylink installed and Xorg should detect it

Comment: What is the output of `lsusb`?

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can tell the general consensus appears to be that if you could get a driver wrapper working then maybe...

I gather, although I could be wrong, that this uses DisplayLink technology and that there should be an open source driver... somewhere: http://www.displaylink.com/news/news/news150509.htm

Which would mean that you want: xserver-xorg-displaylink

If this is the case then there is some advice here on how to get the drivers working: [How To Make Ubuntu 13.04 Work With DisplayLink Monitor?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/321532/how-to-make-ubuntu-13-04-work-with-displaylink-monitor)

However your mileage may vary, I've got zero way of testing any of this out and I am just making an somewhat educated guess.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue, I found a repo that was working a bit, and forked it, you can check it out here:

https://github.com/srw2d/tvlt1421_ubuntu

Hope that helps!