# How To Make Ubuntu 13.04 Work With DisplayLink Monitor?

Tags: 13.04, displaylink

I recently purchased an [AOC E2251FWU DisplayLink](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0073BOCNU) monitor. When I plug this into my [System76 Gazelle Professional](https://www.system76.com/laptops/model/gazp9) running Ubuntu 13.04 Raring Ringtail, nothing happens. Under 'displays', no additional display is detected. On Mac and Windows, this monitor is plug-and-play after installing DisplayLink's drivers.

Having read that previous versions of Ubuntu had plug and play support for DisplayLink monitors, I'm surprised that Ubuntu 13.04 does not! The 'xserver-xorg-displaylink' driver is not available in the 13.04 repositories. I read that it has become baked into the Linux kernel.

Does anybody know how to get a DisplayLink device to actually work on Ubuntu 13.04? I'm looking to get a simple extended display. I've done my due dilligence and Googled around, but no solution I can find works for me.

```
> uname -a
Linux tyrion 3.8.0-26-generic #38-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jun 17 21:43:33 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

> lsmod
Module          Size  Used by
joydev                 17377  0 
pci_stub               12622  1 
vboxpci                23194  0 
vboxnetadp             25670  0 
vboxnetflt             23479  0 
vboxdrv               320372  3 vboxnetadp,vboxnetflt,vboxpci
parport_pc             28152  0 
ppdev                  17073  0 
rfcomm                 42641  0 
bnep                   18036  2 
bluetooth             228619  10 bnep,rfcomm
ip6t_REJECT            12545  1 
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     36913  1 
xt_hl                  12521  6 
ip6t_rt                12529  3 
snd_hda_codec_via      51018  1 
coretemp               13355  0 
kvm_intel             132891  0 
nf_conntrack_ipv6      18335  7 
nf_defrag_ipv6         13201  1 nf_conntrack_ipv6
snd_hda_intel          39619  3 
kvm                   443165  1 kvm_intel
ipt_REJECT             12541  1 
xt_comment             12504  4 
arc4                   12615  2 
xt_LOG                 17400  10 
snd_hda_codec         136453  3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_via,snd_hda_intel
xt_multiport           12597  4 
snd_hwdep              13602  1 snd_hda_codec
xt_limit               12711  13 
xt_tcpudp              12603  22 
snd_pcm                97451  3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel
xt_addrtype            12635  4 
iwldvm                241872  0 
uvcvideo               80847  0 
nf_conntrack_ipv4      14487  7 
snd_page_alloc         18710  2 snd_pcm,snd_hda_intel
nf_defrag_ipv4         12729  1 nf_conntrack_ipv4
snd_seq_midi           13324  0 
xt_state               12578  14 
snd_seq_midi_event     14899  1 snd_seq_midi
mac80211              606457  1 iwldvm
videobuf2_vmalloc      13056  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_memops       13202  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
snd_rawmidi            30180  1 snd_seq_midi
videobuf2_core         40513  1 uvcvideo
videodev              129260  2 uvcvideo,videobuf2_core
ip6table_filter        12815  1 
ip6_tables             27025  1 ip6table_filter
snd_seq                61554  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
nf_conntrack_netbios_ns    12665  0 
nf_conntrack_broadcast    12589  1 nf_conntrack_netbios_ns
snd_seq_device         14497  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
snd_timer              29425  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
nf_nat_ftp             12620  0 
nf_nat                 25867  1 nf_nat_ftp
iwlwifi               173477  1 iwldvm
nf_conntrack_ftp       13342  1 nf_nat_ftp
nf_conntrack           83275  8 nf_nat_ftp,nf_conntrack_netbios_ns,nf_nat,xt_state,nf_conntrack_broadcast,nf_conntrack_ftp,nf_conntrack_ipv4,nf_conntrack_ipv6
microcode              22881  0 
snd                    68876  16 snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_via,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_seq_device
iptable_filter         12810  1 
ip_tables              26995  1 iptable_filter
psmouse                95870  0 
rtsx_pci_ms            13011  0 
cfg80211              510937  3 iwlwifi,mac80211,iwldvm
lp                     17759  0 
soundcore              12680  1 snd
mei                    41158  0 
lpc_ich                17061  0 
memstick               16554  1 rtsx_pci_ms
serio_raw              13215  0 
mac_hid                13205  0 
x_tables               29803  15 ip6table_filter,xt_hl,xt_comment,ip_tables,xt_tcpudp,xt_limit,xt_state,xt_LOG,xt_multiport,iptable_filter,ip6t_rt,ipt_REJECT,ip6_tables,xt_addrtype,ip6t_REJECT
parport                46345  3 lp,ppdev,parport_pc
dm_crypt               22820  1 
udl                    24771  0 
drm_usb                13134  1 udl
syscopyarea            12529  1 udl
sysfillrect            12701  1 udl
sysimgblt              12674  1 udl
rtsx_pci_sdmmc         17475  0 
ghash_clmulni_intel    13259  0 
aesni_intel            55399  4 
aes_x86_64             17255  1 aesni_intel
xts                    12885  1 aesni_intel
lrw                    13257  1 aesni_intel
gf128mul               14951  2 lrw,xts
ablk_helper            13597  1 aesni_intel
cryptd                 20373  4 ghash_clmulni_intel,aesni_intel,ablk_helper
i915                  600396  4 
i2c_algo_bit           13413  1 i915
wmi                    19070  0 
drm_kms_helper         49394  2 udl,i915
video                  19390  1 i915
ahci                   25731  2 
drm                   286028  7 udl,i915,drm_usb,drm_kms_helper
libahci                31364  1 ahci
r8169                  67446  0 
rtsx_pci               33355  2 rtsx_pci_ms,rtsx_pci_sdmmc
```

Comment: So this only work for USB monitor only? (I have nvr seen a usb monitor). I bought a normal monitor and it just come up with a green screen.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Woohoo, I found a solution (no extra adapter required)!

In Ubuntu 13.04, installing the precompiled 3.9 raring kernel from kernel.ubuntu.com makes my display plug-and-play. Using the "Displays" utility, mirroring and extended desktop both work. It's not 100% buttery smooth, but it works. The Saucy 3.10.1 kernel also works just fine with Raring. I can't tell any difference between the 3.9 and 3.10 kernels in terms of DisplayLink.

If your DisplayLink monitor does not work out of the box with Ubuntu 12.10 or 13.04, installing Linux kernel 3.9 or higher may "just work". Apparently the baked in DisplayLink drivers have been improved.

Installing a prebuilt kernel is simple; download the header and image deb files for the kernel of your choice (3 files total). Install the headers first, then the kernel image. Next time you reboot, you should be using the updated kernel (check the version with "uname -r"). If you want to boot into an older kernel again, holding the shift key while your computer is booting will bring up a menu that allows you to select which kernel to boot. If you have issues with a new kernel, you can always uninstall it. I recommend using Synaptic to do so.

http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/

Comment: Yes, I found under Arch Linux too that things just work, finally. I needed to blacklist the udlfb kernel module and install the xorg modesetting driver -- but after that it just works.

Comment: When I plug in, the monitor powers and displays alternating maroon & marine bars. Do you know how to fix that?  My situation here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/89585/displaylink-amd-catalyst-13-8-beta-2

Comment: That looks like a "fun" problem. Sorry, no I don't.

Comment: funniest issue: I got the same issue as user128334, but if I jump to TTY1 (Ctrl+Alt+F1) my terminal actually loads in the USB screen! hahaha with those bars, but I'm unable to turn it on with X...

Answer (score 1):

As an intermediate step, you can place a static image on a DisplayLink device using the instructions here:
https://askubuntu.com/a/393117/46709
If the static image works, then stepping up to the 3.9 Kernel has a chance of working.