# How to configure a second monitor using DisplayLink on Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04, multiple-monitors, displaylink

After following the advice in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/321532/how-to-make-ubuntu-13-04-work-with-displaylink-monitor), the second monitor is detected, and the mirroring option works (although not that smoothly). However, I'm not able to activate the second monitor in the display settings.

I got an error that says `Failed to apply configuration: %s`. I have no idea how to debug this. Any points or work around to fix this?

[image: error message]

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this issue by switching the display off and back on using `xrandr` like so:

```
$ xrandr --output DVI-0 --off
$ xrandr --output DVI-0 --auto
```

I went through this just recently and summed it up on my blog. Eventually, you might be interested to read here:

- http://jochen.kirstaetter.name/blog/linux/using-aoc-usb-monitor-in-ubuntu-1304-displaylink-e1649fwu.html