# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and DisplayLink DL3900 chipset

Tags: unity, 14.04, displaylink

Do I have a chance to get the displayLink adapter (chipset 14.04) working under ubuntu 14.04?

I found only articles for ubuntu 13.04. Is it the same under 14.04?

Comment: http://plugable.com/2014/03/06/displaylink-usb-2-0-graphics-adapters-on-linux-2014-edition this link is for 13.10 if it's of any help

Comment: the links for 13.04 all talk about using kernel 3.9 or greater so it does look like you have a chance.

Answer (score 0):

While there is currently linux kernel support for the older Displaylink chipsets, Startech themselves claims there is currently none for the DL3X00 chipsets.

This is where they say that: http://www.displaylink.com/for-business/common_questions.php (search on the page for 'linux'.)

Bummer!

Answer (score 0):

Since there is a link to download driver for ubuntu 14.04 I guess the answer is 'Yes' (source: http://www.displaylink.com/downloads/ubuntu.php)

Answer (score 0):

Although, their website does say that it is not supported. An employee recently replied to a question on their website saying that it is possible: http://support.plugable.com/plugable/topics/will-the-ud-3900-work-with-linux

> The UD-3900 will probably work for Mint but we do not offer support
>   for this operating system.
>
> Please take a look at the following DisplayLink knowledge base
>   articles:
>
> - [How to install DisplayLink software on Ubuntu](http://support.displaylink.com/knowledgebase/articles/684649-how-to-install-displaylink-software-on-ubuntu)
> - [How to configure DisplayLink displays on Ubuntu](http://support.displaylink.com/knowledgebase/articles/675136-how-to-configure-displaylink-displays-on-ubuntu)
> - [My DisplayLink device does not work on Ubuntu](http://support.displaylink.com/knowledgebase/articles/683672-my-displaylink-device-does-not-work-on-ubuntu)
> - [Known issues with DisplayLink ubuntu support](http://support.displaylink.com/knowledgebase/articles/641668-known-issues-with-displaylink-ubuntu-support)

I am working on this right now and will update you on the procedure I used.

EDIT: I also found another StackExchange answer for this.

[How To Make Ubuntu 13.04 Work With DisplayLink Monitor?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/321532/how-to-make-ubuntu-13-04-work-with-displaylink-monitor?rq=1)