# Startech docking station: Video ports not working

Tags: msi, displaylink, docking

I recently bought an MSI laptop and am running Ubuntu 14.04 on it. 
In order to use several screens, I have also bought a Startech docking station.

[Specifications can be found here](http://www.startech.com/Cards-Adapters/Laptop-docking-stations/Universal-Laptop-Docking-Station-Dual-Monitor~USB3SDOCKHDV), and [review here](http://www.techradar.com/reviews/pc-mac/laptops-portable-pcs/laptop-accessories/startech-universal-usb-3-0-4k-laptop-docking-station-1290412/review)

The whole thing is pretty good, and I can use the USB ports and the Ethernet port of the docking station without problem.

However I have a problem with the VGA, HDMI and DVI ports. None of them work. The screen is basically not detected.

The chipset used in the docking station is [DisplayLink DL-3000](http://www.displaylink.com/technology/dl-3000/). 
[I think this issue is related.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/501438/ubuntu-14-04-lts-and-displaylink-dl3900-chipset)

I was wondering if someone had any information that could help me get the screen working using the docking station.

Any help welcome. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the Displaylink driver which you can get here:

https://support.displaylink.com/forums/287786-displaylink-feature-suggestions/suggestions/35648710-support-ubuntu-18-04